# Generalizing limit-colimit coincidence to Scott-continuous adjunctions: any uses?

Tags: pl.programming-languages, semantics, denotational-semantics, domain-theory

In Abramsky and Jung's 1994 handbook chapter on denotational semantics, after proving that the limit and colimit of expanding sequences exist and coincide, they have the following to say about generalizing this theorem:

> We can generalize Theorem 3.3.7 [the limit-colimit coincidence of expanding sequences in DCPO] [...] we can use
>   general Scott-continuous adjunctions instead of e-p-pairs. [...] By the passage
>   from embeddings to, no longer injective, lower adjoints, we allow domains not only to
>   grow but also to shrink as we move on in the index set. Thus points, which at some
>   stage looked different, may at a later stage be recognized to be the same. [...] For the
>   main text, we must remind ourselves that this generalization has so far not found any
>   application in semantics.

It's been over fifteen years since this chapter was written. Have there been any applications of this generalization in semantics since then?